# Why is object 'destructed' twice?

Tags: c++, destructor

In the following code the destructor for `a` is called twice, and the first call seems to be ignored:

```
struct A1
{
    int A;
    A1(int a=0) : A(a) { std::cout << "ctor: " << A << "\n"; std::cout.flush(); }
    ~A1() { std::cout << "dtor: " << A << "\n"; std::cout.flush(); }
};


int main()
{
    A1 a(1), *pa=new A1(2), *pb=new A1(3);

    a.~A1();
    pa->~A1();
    delete pb;
    std::cout << "'destructed' a.A = " << a.A << "\n"; std::cout.flush();

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
ctor: 1
ctor: 2
ctor: 3
dtor: 1
dtor: 2
dtor: 3
'destructed' a.A = 1
dtor: 1
```

What is happening here?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. When `a` goes out of scope, its destructor is called. Also, you print `a.A` when `a` is in a desroyed state.

Comment: @40two: thx for the link - I used wrong search terms & didn't find it myself.

Answer (score 10):

Unless you really know what you are doing, you should never directly call the destructor of an object. Instead, allow the destructor to be called when you `delete` an object (that was allocated with `new`) or when it goes out of scope.

In your case `a.~A1();` will lead to undefined behavior, because you'll call the destructor again when `a` goes out of scope.

Comment: Thx for the answer but the link provided by 40two above shows that this question is a dupe & I'll ask for it to be deleted - sorry for your loss of rep ...

Comment: @slashmais: No worries. Internet points are not that important.

Comment: @slashmais don't delete the question. The fact that is a duplicate doesn't matter, maybe some future reader will find your question more suitable than the one I posted :).